# I’d rather + different subject (+ past simple clause)

Tags: grammar

I'm looking at [this tutorial](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/would-rather-would-sooner) that shows the following usage:

> same subject (+ base form)
>
> I’d rather stay at home than go out
> tonight.
>
> different subject (+ past simple clause):
>
> **I’d rather you** stayed at home
> tonight.

I don't remember hearing this structure before. How common is that? I'd probably say:

> I’d rather have you stay at home

Is this an equivalent and grammatically correct?

Comment: @YosefBaskin, thanks. So is the former in common usage? And can you please clarify `hints that you hope the stayed at home comes from you (the other person).`?

Comment: Although the expression is not entirely uncommon, it looks grammatically incorrect to me. The modal verb "would" needs to be followed by the main verb, which is not the case in the expression "I'd rather you stayed at home tonight." It appears that there are two clauses here: 1) I would rather 2) You stayed at home tonight. "Rather" is not a verb, and therefore, "would" is functioning without another verb. Isn't that odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the two versions are practically the same, your question is a matter of interpretation.

Let's say you are talking to me. "I’d rather you stayed at home tonight" hints that you hope the *stayed at home* part comes from me.  You hope that **I want to stay** home. The form is uncommon in the US.

"I'd rather have you stay at home" says that you want my company at home. The directness makes it very American. Emphasis on **rather have  you**, since that is the action that I prefer. [Fanny Brice - I'd Rather Be Blue Over You.](http://youtube.com/watch?v=_62pKiiVSIs)

Comment: got it, thanks, I'm wondering if it's common in BE

Comment: Don't ask, I'm in New Jersey.

Comment: Just thought of another alternative: `I prefer that you stay home` - can you  please say anything about it?

Comment: yeah :) but in the context of the question?

Comment: It is fine to say I prefer that you stay home.

Comment: What makes "I'd rather you stayed at home" grammatical -- does it have a form of subjunctive or something? I find it acceptable too, but I don't know why it's acceptable. // And is "I'd rather you stay at home" grammatical too?

Comment: @Mr, Yes, _I would_ say that the structure is subjunctive.